# JavaFx get return from second window

Tags: user-interface, javafx

I am programming a GUI with JavaFx and I don't really know how to connect everything.
I have a Main Window and within the main window I have a button that opens another window which allows me to pick a customer.
Now I already struggle with giving the information of the picked customer back to the Main Window because I don't have a return method to open it.

I open it this way:
public void openSecondWindow(ActionEvent event) {

```
     Parent root;
     try {
         root = FXMLLoader
                 
    .load(getClass().getResource("....secondWindow.fxml"));
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setTitle("Second Window");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        stage.show();
```

I don't initalize the Second Window myself and I don't have an object like
SecondWindow sc = new SecondWindow(); so I could call something like sc.getCustomer.

Probably it's easy to solve but I'm lacking the right vocabulary to google it.

Comment: Consider using a [`Dialog<Customer>`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html) (read the Javadoc to understand how to use) and using `showAndWait()` to get an `Optional<Customer>`. Otherwise, use `stage.showAndWait()` then afterwards get the FXML controller from the `FXMLLoader` and call a method which returns the chosen `Customer`. The `Dialog` approach is likely cleaner.

Comment: Thank you. For this window I really like the Dialog approach, but later in the Programm I need another window with a lot of functions and I want to have in a separated class. Also the main point is I can build it with the scene builder.

Comment: @GrimSqueaker You can still use SceneBuilder to create a complex panel that you use as the content of a Dialog.  I sometimes use a static method of the controller class to show a dialog that is initialized mostly from the FXML.

Comment: As noted by @swpalmer, you can still use Scene Builder to create a `Dialog`. For instance, you could either (1) design the `DialogPane` and set it on the `Dialog` in code or (2) design an arbitrary scene graph and set the `content` of the `DialogPane` in code. Also, not sure if Scene Builder is capable of it, but you can even define the entire `Dialog` in FXML.

Comment: Ididn't know and couldn't find  the loader.getController() Method. I think that was what @Slaw was referring to.

Answer (score 0):

To close the question, my solution looked like this:

`SecondWindow sc = loader.getController();`

And then I could call my modified Method like `scOpenWithData(int id){....}`

`sc.scOpenWithData(123);`

In the whole:

```
 Parent root;
 try {
     FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(
            getClass().getResource("....secondWindow.fxml"));
    root = loader.load();
    SecondWindow sc = loader.getController();
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.setTitle("Second Window");
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    sc.scOpenWithData(123);
    stage.showAndWait();
```